# Schema Changes to Integrate Facebook and Google Login

Tags: sql-server, database-design

I have `Users` table to store user details with password and the authentication for the Application is working good with this.

But we want to integrate `Facebook` and `Google` Login in our system so please advise the related schema modifications.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Users(
    UserId      int IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
    UserTypeId  int,            -- Admin = 1, End User = 2. (We have a master table for this, but eliminating here for simplicity)
    UserName    nvarchar(16) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    UserPassword nvarchar(16),
    FirstName   nvarchar(64),
    LastName    nvarchar(64),
    DateOfBirth date,
    Gender      char(1),
    PhoneNumber nvarchar(16),
    Email       nvarchar(128) UNIQUE,
    IsActive    bit,
    UpdateTime  datetime default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP )
```

**Here is what I am thinking:**
1) Once the user authenticated from Facebook or Google then the application will have claims (emailId)
2) The application should validate the emailId existence in Users Table and if exists it will allow login.

Q1> So will this require any update for the existing Row in Users Table?
Q2> If the user record does not exists (based on emailId claim record) then I think we should add the new record in users table?
Q3> In case of Add: What will be the Username and Password values?
Q4> Can the user (the added record) do a normal login without Facebook login?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to accept OpenID logins, you will have to accept and store the users' OpenID-URLs. This URL identifies the user just like an email address does.

Q1: Depends: If you want to allow both OpenID-logins and normal login for the same user, you will have to add another column to the table. If you don't allow mixed logins, you could use your `Email` column to store the OpenID URL.

Q2: Yes, if you see a new OpenID-URL, handle it just like an unknown email address

Q3: You will have to ask the user to pick a username - I assume you do the same for your current users. If you want to allow both logins for the same user, you will have to ask the user to set a password - otherwise they can only login through their OpenID provider.

Q4: Only if you did ask for a username and a password (see Q3)

Please note that allowing the same user to login through OpenID and using conventional username/password introduces potential security problem: A user might not unserstand that you're asking them to *set* a password and enter their Facebook (or Google) password. Or they might just not care and use the same password everywhere. If they do so and your database does not encrypt the password properly, your database will store the Facebook names *and* unencrypted passwords... even if just 10% used the same password on your site - just imagine what they could do with that.

Comment: thanks a lot for your view/idea/suggestion. It helped a lot. I will think about the Db changes as per your suggestion. Also your advise on security risk is very good to know, thanks for that too. I am sorry as I cant vote Up your post because of less reputations, else +1 for your Answer.

Comment: Yes it is. Still looking for better options if some once can advise.

Comment: I don't think there are a lot of other options.